# How to get "items" column in orders panel in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Since WooCommerce major update 3.0+ the "Purchased" column in backend orders list panel has been removed. This column previously showed a toggle list of items in the order for quick viewing.

How to Get back this "items" column in orders panel?

If there is any hook for that? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to have been [removed](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/1c10ad94cbde79aa910caf7c61422563c72fef11) for performance reasons, but you could look at the code that was removed and add it back via the `manage_shop_order_posts_columns` filter and `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` action.

```
/**
 * Modify the custom columns for orders.
 * @param  array $columns
 * @return array
 */
function so_43719068_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {

    // the new column as an array for subsequent array manip
    $new_column = array( 'order_items' => __( 'Purchased', 'your-plugin' ) );

    $insert_after = 'order_title';

    // insert after specified column
    if( isset( $columns[ $insert_after ] ) ){

        // find the "title" column
        $index =  array_search( $insert_after, array_keys( $columns) );

        // reform the array
        $columns = array_merge( array_slice( $columns, 0, $index + 1, true ), $new_column, array_slice( $columns, $index, count( $columns ) - $index, true ) );

    // or add to end
    } else {
        $columns = array_merge( $columns, $new_column );
    }

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'so_43719068_shop_order_columns', 20 );



/**
 * Output custom columns for orders.
 * @param string $column
 * @param int $post_id
 */
function so_43719068_render_shop_order_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $the_order;

    if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() !== $post_id ) {
        $the_order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
    }

    switch ( $column ) :

        case 'order_items' :

            /* translators: %d: order items count */
            echo '<a href="#" class="show_order_items">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_count', sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', $the_order->get_item_count(), 'woocommerce' ), $the_order->get_item_count() ), $the_order ) . '</a>';

            if ( sizeof( $the_order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {

                echo '<table class="show_order_items" cellspacing="0">';

                foreach ( $the_order->get_items() as $item ) {
                    $product        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $item->get_product(), $item );
                    $item_meta_html      = wc_display_item_meta( $item, array( 'echo' => false ) );
                    ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_class', '', $item, $the_order ); ?>">
                        <td class="qty"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_quantity() ); ?></td>
                        <td class="name">
                            <?php  if ( $product ) : ?>
                                <?php echo ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && $product->get_sku() ) ? $product->get_sku() . ' - ' : ''; ?><a href="<?php echo get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ); ?></a>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ( ! empty( $item_meta_html ) ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_help_tip( $item_meta_html ); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }

                echo '</table>';

            } else echo '&ndash;';
        break;

    endswitch;

}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'so_43719068_render_shop_order_columns', 10, 2 );
```